# Draw triangle on right-border

Tags: css, html, css-shapes

I have a ul element with many li. Some lines (li) are highlighted with yellow background.

I want to add a triangle to the right border. This triangle should looks like an **arrow that point to the text**.

Something like this:
[image]

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zen5vvzw/)

I tried to draw this triangle with right border, but this not giving me the right shape.

```
<ul>
    <li>not highlighted</li>
    <li>not highlighted</li>
    <li class="highlighted">HIGHLIGHTED</li>
    <li>not highlighted</li>
</ul>
<style>
.highlighted {
    border-right: 20px solid red;
}
</style>
```

Please give a notice on the that one li can contain more the one line, so the height of the line can be changed. Arrow with fixed height (of one line) is good enough.

Is this possible? If yes, how?

Comment: you could us an image and make I background of the li! and position it where you want

Comment: Use both `:after` *and* `:before`: http://jsfiddle.net/zen5vvzw/1/

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should do it (but I doubt you can get outlined arrow without an image - only full).

```css
.highlighted:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-top: 10px solid transparent;
  border-bottom: 10px solid transparent;
  border-right: 10px solid red;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li>not highlighted</li>
  <li>not highlighted</li>
  <li class="highlighted">HIGHLIGHTED</li>
  <li>not highlighted</li>
</ul>
```

Based on [this tutorial](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/).

Answer (score 7):

You can use [transform](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transforms) and [Pseudo-elements](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Pseudo-elements)

```css
li{
  height: 20px;
  line-height: 20px;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 10px
}
li.highlighted:before, li.highlighted:after{
  content: '';
  position: absolute
}
li.highlighted:before{
  width: 12px;
  height: 12px;
  right: 10px;
  transform: rotate(45deg);
  border-left: 2px solid red;
  border-bottom: 2px solid red
}
li.highlighted:after{
  height: 20px;
  width: 2px;
  right: 15px;
  background: red;
  top: -3px
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>not highlighted</li>
    <li>not highlighted</li>
    <li class="highlighted">HIGHLIGHTED</li>
    <li>not highlighted</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: @No1Lives4Ever you should consider accepting this as the correct answer. It's better

Comment: Better, if the outlined sketch was indeed what he wanted... But it's a nice solution, I upvoted it too.

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```css
li{ 
    position: relative;
}

.highlighted:after, .highlighted:before { 
    right: 0px;
    top: 50%;
    border: solid transparent;
    content: " ";
    height: 0;
    width: 0;
    position: absolute;
    pointer-events: none; 

} 

.highlighted:after {
    border-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0);
    border-right-color: #fff;
    border-width: 6px;
    margin-top: -6px;
} 
.highlighted:before { 
    border-color: rgba(245, 23, 7, 0);
    border-right-color: #f51707;
    border-width: 9px;
    margin-top: -9px;
}
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>not highlighted</li>
    <li>not highlighted</li>
    <li class="highlighted">HIGHLIGHTED</li>
    <li>not highlighted</li>
</ul>
```